# Loading xib dynamically but wrong one displaying

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have an universal app that I am trying to share a viewController code with.  I have this:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    AboutController *screen = [[AboutController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPhoneAboutController" bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];    
}
else
{
    AboutController *screen = [[AboutController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];    
}
```

Although this is loading, and when I step through the code, it does hit the xib for the iPhone but it seems to always be loading the iPad version.  I know this because in the xib file for the iPhone, I have manually added different background images and it never shows.  In the iPhone simulator it shows the iPad version where it is off screen.

Also, if I step through the code in the controller, it does show that the load is the iPhone yet display is all iPad objects.  In the iPhone xib, I do have the Files Owner set to the AboutController.

This is the first time I am attempting to "share code".  I know I can just create separate class files with the same code but this seems senseless.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Geo...

Comment: Can we see the initWithNibName method from AboutController? That might be where the issue it. Also, that might be a better place to put this logic. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes it did have one which I commented out and it still only loads the iPad version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters: make sure you don't override nib initialization in your `AboutController`.

If not, try cleaning your project (also delete your app's folders in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`). Also uninstall the app from device and then rebuild.

Comment: Tried all of that and it still loads the xib for iPad.  Arrhhh!